# Android View.Animation size jumped when used with other set of animation. Why?

Tags: android

I follow the view.animation sample here https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation and encounter some strange problem.

To illustrate the problem I prolong the duration from 700ms to 2000ms with the same code as below.

```
<set android:shareInterpolator="false"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <scale
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:toXScale="1.4"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="1.4"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:fillAfter="false"
        android:duration="2000" />
    <set android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator">
        <scale
            android:fromXScale="1.4"
            android:toXScale="0.0"
            android:fromYScale="1.4"
            android:toYScale="0.0"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:startOffset="2000"
            android:duration="400"
            android:fillBefore="false" />
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="0"
            android:toDegrees="-45"
            android:toYScale="0.0"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:startOffset="2000"
            android:duration="400" />
    </set>
</set>
```

You notice the initial animation, the `Hello World!` size jumped at the start, as shown in the gif below. This is strange because the `fromXScale` and `fromYScale` start from `1.0` so I'm expecting a gradual size change instead of a jumped.

[image: Unexpcted jumped in size at the start]

If I remove the second set of animation and leave the code as below

```
<set android:shareInterpolator="false"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <scale
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:toXScale="1.4"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="1.4"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:fillAfter="false"
        android:duration="2000" />
</set>
```

then the animation looks smooth, increase it's size from 1.0 to 1.4 accordingly as shown below.

[image: Expected behavior]

Why is the jump in size?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the code we need to set the second set `fromXScale` and `fromYScale` to `1.0` first.

```
<set android:shareInterpolator="false"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <scale
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:toXScale="1.4"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="1.4"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:fillAfter="false"
        android:duration="2000" />
    <set android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator">
        <scale
            android:fromXScale="1.0"
            android:toXScale="0.0"
            android:fromYScale="1.0"
            android:toYScale="0.0"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:startOffset="2000"
            android:duration="400"
            android:fillBefore="false" />
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="0"
            android:toDegrees="-45"
            android:toYScale="0.0"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:startOffset="2000"
            android:duration="400" />
    </set>
</set>
```

Then the animation will be smooth as below.

[image]

The code in https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation does confuses a little on how that behaves.